# Implementing a fragment shader that behaves similar to glColor4f

Tags: opengl-es

I'd like to implement a shader which acts similar to the `glColor4f` fixed function method.

shader :

```
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  //gl_FragColor = vColor
};
```

drawing function

```
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, cube1);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
```

This code draws a cube with green color. Now, I want to change it to a different color, for example, red. I want to do this without modifying the shader code every time a different color should be used. Instead, it should be possible to do something similar to what was possible with the `glColor4f` method:

1. Set color 1 // act as glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
2. glDrawElements // draw obj 1
3. Set color 2 // act as glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
4. glDrawElements // draw obj 2

How can this be done by using shaders?

Comment: I edited your question to be more clearly written. Could you please check if everything is still correct?

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this you can use uniforms. Just declare one in your shader:

```
uniform vec4 in_Color;
void main () {
  gl_FragColor = in_Color;
}
```

Then you will need to get the uniform location by calling glGetUniformLocation with your **program** (not shader!) and uniform names (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml)

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "in_Color");
```

Next step is to set uniform values, in this case use glUniform4f to do this:

```
glUniform4f(location, r, g, b, a);
```

This way you can use glUniform4f call as glColor4f.